# ERROR: Error 1067: Invalid default value for ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I run the script from Workbench. Here is the complete script:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

---

-- Schema mydb

---

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`categories`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`categories` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`categories` (
  `categories_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `categories_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `categories_image` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `parent_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` INT(3) NULL,
  `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories_id`),
  INDEX `fk_categories_categories1_idx` (`parent_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_categories1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`categories` (`categories_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`manufacturers`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`manufacturers` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`manufacturers` (
  `manufacturers_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `manufacturers_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturers_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`products`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products` (
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_model` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `products_price` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `products_weight` DECIMAL(4,2) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `manufacturers_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  INDEX `fk_products_manufacturers1_idx` (`manufacturers_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `manufacturers_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturers_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`manufacturers` (`manufacturers_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`categories_has_products`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`categories_has_products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`categories_has_products` (
  `categories_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories_id`, `products_id`),
  INDEX `fk_categories_has_products_products_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_categories_has_products_categories_idx` (`categories_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `categories_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`categories` (`categories_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `products_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`products_description`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products_description` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products_description` (
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `products_description` TEXT NULL,
  `products_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `products_viewed` INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `products_name_UNIQUE` (`products_name` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `products_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`customers`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`customers` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customers` (
  `customers_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_gender` CHAR(1) NULL,
  `customers_firstname` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `customers_lastname` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_dob` DATE NULL,
  `customers_email_address` VARCHAR(96) NULL,
  `customers_default_address_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `customers_telephone` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_fax` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_password` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `customers_newsletter` CHAR(1) NULL,
  `customers_info_date_of_last_logon` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `customers_info_number_of_logons` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customers_info_date_account_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `customers_info_date_account_last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customers_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`reviews`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`reviews` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`reviews` (
  `reviews_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customers_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customers_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `reviews_rating` INT(1) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `reviews_read` INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `reviews_text` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reviews_id`),
  INDEX `fk_reviews_products1_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_reviews_customers1_idx` (`customers_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reviews_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reviews_customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customers_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customers` (`customers_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`specials`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`specials` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`specials` (
  `specials_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `specials_new_products_price` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `specials_date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `specials_last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`specials_id`),
  INDEX `fk_specials_products1_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_specials_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`orders`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`orders` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`orders` (
  `orders_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `customers_street_address` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `customers_suburb` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_city` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `customers_postcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `customers_state` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_country` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_telephone` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `customers_email_address` VARCHAR(96) NULL,
  `delivery_name` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `delivery_street_address` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `delivery_suburb` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `delivery_city` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `delivery_postcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `delivery_state` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `delivery_country` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `payment_method` VARCHAR(12) NULL,
  `cc_type` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `cc_owner` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `cc_number` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `cc_expires` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
  `last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_purchased` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `shipping_cost` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NULL,
  `shipping_method` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `orders_status` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `orders_date_finished` DATETIME NULL,
  `comments` TEXT NULL,
  `currency` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
  `currency_value` DECIMAL(16,6) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`),
  INDEX `fk_orders_customers1_idx` (`customers_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_customers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customers_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customers` (`customers_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`ordered_products`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`ordered_products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ordered_products` (
  `orders_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_size_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_color_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_price` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`, `products_id`, `products_size_id`, `products_color_id`),
  INDEX `fk_orders_has_products_products1_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_orders_has_products_orders1_idx` (`orders_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_has_products_orders1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`orders_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`orders` (`orders_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_has_products_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`ordered_products`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`ordered_products` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ordered_products` (
  `orders_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_size_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_color_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_price` DECIMAL(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`, `products_id`, `products_size_id`, `products_color_id`),
  INDEX `fk_orders_has_products_products1_idx` (`products_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_orders_has_products_orders1_idx` (`orders_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_has_products_orders1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`orders_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`orders` (`orders_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_has_products_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`products_size`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products_size` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products_size` (
  `products_size_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_size_name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_size_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`products_color`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products_color` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products_color` (
  `products_color_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_color_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_color_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `mydb`.`products_attributes`

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`products_attributes` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products_attributes` (
  `products_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_size_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_color_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_quantity` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `products_image` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `products_date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `products_last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `products_date_available` DATETIME NULL,
  `products_status` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`, `products_size_id`, `products_color_id`),
  INDEX `fk_products_attributes_products_sizes1_idx` (`products_size_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_products_attributes_products_colors1_idx` (`products_color_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_attributes_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`products_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_attributes_products_sizes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_size_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products_size` (`products_size_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_attributes_products_colors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`products_color_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products_color` (`products_color_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

And here is the complete error:

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1067: Invalid default value for 'last_modified'
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`categories` (
          `categories_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `categories_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
          `categories_image` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
          `parent_id` INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `sort_order` INT(3) NULL,
          `date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          `last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          PRIMARY KEY (`categories_id`),
          INDEX `fk_categories_categories1_idx` (`parent_id` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_categories1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`categories` (`categories_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the `SQL_MODE` you are setting.

`TRADITIONAL` and `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` restricts the `TIMESTAMP` type columns for not being set with a default value.

By defining any of the following should work on `TIMESTAMP` type columns.

```
DEFAULT 0
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Alternately, by just setting the `SQL_MODE` to `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` would need no changes to your script.

---

**Others**:
Constraint names MUST be *unique*. Table `products_description` defines `Constraint products_id` but the same name was already used in table `categories_has_products`.

Maintain unique constraint names.

**Refer to**:

- [Important SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important)
- [TRADITIONAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional)
- [ALLOW_INVALID_DATES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates)

Comment: ***@Mr.Hyde***: Said table from the pastebin seems out of context from current question. If you are not the owner of the question, I suggest you add your question expecting better answers.

Answer (score 6):

Change the SQL_MODE like below:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES’;
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `last_modified` cannot be `null` by your definition, you have to provide a default value as well:

```
`last_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and too many dates to change.  I set this at the top of my .sql script and all was well.

```
SET sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure if its correct but I set on "my sql settings -> sql-mode as none or something like this (the other beyond "sql-mode -> user-mode") solved  my problem

Answer (score 0):

So in my case ubuntu 16.04 instance with lemp 
i had to change the mysql time stamp so log into mysql and execute below commands

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: and to set the same thing in configuration file sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION  set this in the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf