# How to create SQL table properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL table with the following syntax in MySQL Workbench (in Mac OS),

```
CREATE TABLE orders (

        order_id                    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        company_id                  INT  NOT NULL, 
        customer_id                 INT NOT NULL, 
        order_number                VARCHAR(200), 
        order_date                  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
        created                     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
        order_status                INT NOT NULL, 

        CONSTRAINT orders_fk_company 
            FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies (company_id), 

        CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customer 
            FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id)

    );
```

When I'm trying to execute this script, I'm getting the following message,

```
Error code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'created'
```

What is the issue here and how to create the table properly ? I have other 2 tables namely companies and customers provided below. There are executing properly and no issue there.

```
CREATE TABLE companies (

company_id                  INT     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
company_name                VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL, 
contact_name                VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL, 
contact_phone               VARCHAR(30)         NOT NULL, 
contact_email               VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL, 
created                     DATETIME            NOT NULL 

);

CREATE TABLE customers (

customer_id                 INT             NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
company_id                  INT                NOT NULL, 
customer_name               VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL, 
customer_company            VARCHAR(100), 
CONSTRAINT customers_fk_company 
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies (company_id) 

);
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `TIMESTAMP` into `DATETIME`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860351/mysql-column-type-timestamp-implicitly-includes-not-null-default-current-time) question and its answer might help. Check which MySQL version are you using.

Comment: I just copied your **`CREATE`** statements and ran them on 5.5 with no errors.

Comment: I'm using 6.3 in mac and changing TIMESTAMP into DATETIME gets the job done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312144/error-error-1067-invalid-default-value-for-on-update-current-timestamp Check this one. It might help.